# Use REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract string of varied length

Tags: sql, teradata, regexp-substr

I want to extract alphanumeric text of varied length from a string between the second occurrence of a specific characters.

I have tried various forms of substr and regexp_substr but can't seem to get the syntax right. This is for use in Teradata SQL assistant. In the past I would have to create a temp table and use substr twice before trimming down the string to what I need. I want to do it all in one go.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Channel:DF GB, Order Num:12345T6, Order Date:01/01/2019, Charge Codes:TAXES,,GBRAX', 'Num\\:+(\\:+)',1,2, ':') as RESULTING_STRING
```

My desired result is to return ONLY what is between "Num:" and the next "," in this case "12345T6". The length of the order number can vary so it is not a fixed length. When I run my code the actual output is a '?' returned by Teradata. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've tagged your question for multiple databases. Which one are you actually using, Teradata or Oracle?

Comment: I am using Teradata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Teradata SQL Assistant to query a Teradata system (but why do you tag Oracle then) the RegEx syntax is slightly different (both use a different RegEx dialects):

Teradata's RegExp_Substr doesn't support the *subexpression* parameter, you can either switch to the (I really don't know why) undocumented `RegExp_Substr_gpl`

```
RegExp_Substr_gpl(x, 'Num:([^,]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

or tell the RegEx to forget the previous match using `\K`:

```
RegExp_Substr(x, 'Num:\K[^,]*', 1,1, 'i')
```

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the Oracle tag. This answered my question.

Comment: Learned that GPL is part of the GNU, or open software group.  Looks like someone else wrote the function and made it available to all.  Probably why it is not documented in official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Channel:DF GB, Order Num:12345T6, Order Date:01/01/2019, Charge Codes:TAXES,,GBRAX', 'Num:(\w*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as RESULTING_STRING from dual
```

Finds `Num:` and then captures as many word characters (`,` is not a word char) as there are available. The last parameter - `subexpr` - specifies which subexpression (aka capture group) you want, without it the whole thing will be matched (`Num:12345T6`).

Answer (score 0):

### You can give a try to the below pattern search !

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ((REGEXP_SUBSTR('Channel:DF GB, Order Num:12345T6, Order Date:01/01/2019, Charge Codes:TAXES,,GBRAX', 'Num:[A-Za-z0-9]*',1,1, 'i')),'Num:','',1,1,'i')  AS RESULTING_STRING
```

Regexp_substr pattern search ['Num:[A-Za-z0-9]*'], will first filter out the alphanumeric characters that follow the pattern 'Num:',astriek, helps to find out zero or more occurrences of the specified pattern.

For eg:, in this 'Num:12345T6' will be filtered out of the string provided, also note the last parameter in the regexp_substr is 'i', which ensures case in-specific search.

Lastly, Regexp_replace will replace the pattern 'Num:' from the output of the regexp_substr with an empty string,resulting in a final string as '12345T6'.